# scrapy splash - SplashFormRequest with wrong args

Tags: web, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm new to splash and I just implemented it into scrapy and tried to use it to replace one classic scrapy request with it (as my pages I want to scrape uses some js). so far I have :

```
        for a in res_json['data']:
            req = SplashFormRequest(
            'my_url_to_request',
            self.fill_details, #my callback
            args={'http_method': 'POST', 'body': "valeur="+str(a['id'])},
            )
            yield req
```

thing is I've been looking to find a way to set my headers and also my cookies but I can't find a way (even so the doc talk about it I don't understandthe best way to do so ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried setting the `cookies` arg to the `SplashFormRequest`?

Comment: I'v read the doc and haven't seen such an arg

Comment: See https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/312